# LinearLayout and FrameLayout for positioning buttons

Tags: java, android, android-layout, button, position

I tried to figure this out on my own for hours already and just can't make it. Here it what I am trying to do: [Image of desired layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nrzgq.jpg)

The "blue" rectangle is the area the TextSwitcher is supposed to encompass, but I can't manage to put the "Redo Set" directly above the "Previous Item" and the "Next Set" directly above the "Next Item" button. Here is my layout xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextSwitcher
    android:id="@+id/textSwitcherMain"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    android:text="" >

    </TextSwitcher>

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/problematicButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:text="@string/problematic" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/playButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right|top"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:text="@string/play_1" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/nextSetButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:text="@string/next_set" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/redoSetButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:text="@string/redo_set" />

</FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/previousButton"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/previous_item_button" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/nextButton"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/next_item_button" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView 
    ads:adUnitId="**************"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I tried putting nextButton and previousButton in the FrameLayout, but then they overlap with redoSetButton and nextSetButton respectively. Also, nextButton and previousButton should each take up 50% of the width, so I somewhat have to put it into a LinearLayout and I tried putting various combinations inside the FrameLayout, but I can't manage to position those buttons in this way. 
Furthermore, it's important that all those buttons are on top of the TextSwitcher, because it will have a background image/colouring that should be visible behind the buttons.

This is my first posting. I hope I was detailed enough. Thanks for your input in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner_1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner_2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner_3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextSwitcher
            android:id="@+id/textSwitcherMain"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:keepScreenOn="true"
            android:text="" >

        </TextSwitcher>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/problematicButton"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/problematic" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/playButton"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/play_1" />

            </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nextSetButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/next_set" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/redoSetButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/redo_set" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/previousButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/previous_item_button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nextButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/next_item_button" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            ads:adUnitId="**************"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: "Previous Item" and "Next Item" have to be drawn on TextSwitcher, which is unfortunately not the case here, as they are displayed below the TextSwitcher area now. I know it might be hard to understand what I mean. Also, redoSetButton/nextSetButton/problematicButton/playButton should stay (size-wise) the same (as in my code), so I don't want them to fill up the whole width. The way you put it, they each take up 50% of the width. Thanks for your effort though.